# Toolbar menu item unable to set icon

Tags: android, xml, menu, icons

Been at this for a while and tried numerous permutations of below menu XML but no matter what I cannot seem to change the icon (i'm trying to set a filter list icon), instead I always get the "three dots" icon.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Menu XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<group
    android:id="@+id/action_filter"
    android:checkableBehavior="single"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_action_filter_list_light"
    app:showAsAction="always">
    <item android:id="@+id/watchlist_filter_all"
        android:title="All"
        />
    <item android:id="@+id/watchlist_filter_action"
        android:title="Action"
        />
    <item android:id="@+id/watchlist_filter_comedy"
        android:title="Comedy"
        />
    <item android:id="@+id/watchlist_filter_drama"
        android:title="Drama"
        />
</group>
```

Comment: Can you try `android:showAsAction="always"`?

Comment: Tried it already and no change.

Comment: I have this set already and makes no difference, icon still shows as three dots?

Comment: Don't use a group. Use only items

Answer (score 0):

You are using appcompat v7 i guess,

This should make it happen (in onCreate of activity):

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Already set and makes no difference. Its something to do with using a menu group. If I set above XML as a simple menu item the icon will show. Very strange..